# karate options in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, karate

I am trying to run code from jenkins giving specific tag in Goals and options.But it fails with following error.Can you please validate the syntax and let me know how to resolve this
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project karate-boilerplate: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete

```
 clean compile test  -Dkarate.options="--tags @reg"
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look like an issue with karate, error says

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project karate-boilerplate: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete

maven is failing to `clean` your `target` directory. from the complete logs, you should be able to see the exact file which maven is not able to delete.

In the logs carefully look after **Failed to delete** statement. it should be pointing to a file.

Comment: I suspect you have a locally hosted Jenkins and have opened your reports/logs directly from the project directory :)